# If $E$ and $P$ don't commute, why could we have an $E$-$K$ diagram?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, commutator, observables

If $E$ (energy) and $P$ (momentum) only commute in constant potential, how could we have an $E$-$K$ diagram in a solid material?

$[E,p] \neq 0$. Then we cannot prepare electrons whose $E$ and $P$ are both very specified.
However, in solid state material, we often have $E$-$K$ diagram, where every point is a pair of specified $E$ and $P$.
The potential in a solid is definitely not a constant, so can somebody explain this?

Answer (score 11):

In the band diagrams you refer to, $K$ is not actually momentum; instead, it is something called [crystal momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_momentum) (also often 'quasimomentum'; for more details and its relationship to real momentum see [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/243946/physical-meaning-of-crystal-momentum), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1725/is-crystal-momentum-really-momentum), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/265301/relationship-between-crystal-momentum-and-true-momentum) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/99620/dispersion-relation-e-vs-k-clarification-crystal-momentum-or-electron-moment) questions, among many others on this site).

In short, $\hat H$ does not commute with $\hat p$, but it does commute with a restricted subset of operators which are *functions* of $\hat p$. In particular, it can be seen that the operator
$$
\hat U(a) = e^{i\hat p a/\hbar}
$$
produces a translation by $a$ in position space by the displacement $a$. If the hamiltonian has the form
$$
\hat H = \frac{1}{2m} \hat p^2 + V(\hat x)
$$
where $V(x+a)=V(x)$ is a periodic potential, then generically $\hat H$ will not commute with arbitrary displacements, i.e. $[\hat H, e^{i\hat p \tilde a/\hbar}] \neq 0$ for arbitrary $\tilde a$, but it *will* commute with $e^{i\hat p \tilde a/\hbar}$ when $\tilde a = a$, i.e. when the displacement length matches the period of the potential.

Thus, we have
$$
[\hat H, e^{i\hat p \tilde a/\hbar}] = 0,
$$
which means that $\hat H$ and $e^{i\hat p \tilde a/\hbar}$ admit a common eigenbasis. Moreover, $\hat U(a) = e^{i\hat p a/\hbar}$ is a unitary operator, which means that all of its eigenvalues must have unit modulus and it is always possible to write them as $u = e^{ik a/\hbar}$, where $k$ is only ever defined up to a multiple of $2\pi\hbar/a$; to remove this ambiguity, we restrict ourselves only to $k$'s in the interval $(-\pi\hbar/a, \pi \hbar/a]$.

This $k$ is the crystal momentum that's used in the band diagrams you're bothered by. While it does have a nontrivial relationship with physical momentum, it is *not* the same thing.

Answer (score -4):

This is not an answer to your question, but rather a response to the premise you wrote, to clear up a misconception: Energy and momentum *can* commute in a non-constant potential, it just depends what the potential is. You'd have to check it explicitly for a given potential by acting the momentum operator on the potential on a test function.

In general, in any closed system (so no *external* potential), momentum is conserved, which means we must have 
$$[H,p_i]=0$$

Why should they commute? A conserved quantity commutes with $H$ so that its time evolution is unaffected, thus it is conserved:
$$P(t)=e^{-itH} P e^{itH}=P e^{-itH} e^{itH}=P$$

**Edit**: In the comments it was suggested that the claim above was false. So as an important example, below is a proof of this for the coulomb potential of two charge particles of mass $m$. Note that the conserved quantity is the *summed* (total) momentum of both particles, $\vec{p}_1+\vec{p}_2$. The individual momenta are not conserved and do not commute with $H$.

$$[H,p]$$
$$=[p_1^2/2m +p_2^2/2m+V(x_1,x_2), p_1 +p_2]$$

The first two terms of the hamiltonian commute with the total momentum so they vanish.
$$=[V(x_1,x_2), p_1 + p_2]$$
$$=[V(x_1,x_2), p_1]+[V(x_1,x_2),p_2]$$

Consider the first commutator, for $p_1$. Use the notation $\partial_{x1}\equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}$.

$$[V(x_1,x_2), p_1]$$
$$=-i\hbar[V(x_1,x_2), \partial_{x1}]$$

where $V(x_1, x_2)=\frac{-k}{|x_2-x_1|}$

Let's find this commutator. Consider on some test function $\psi(x_1, x_2)$

$$\partial_{x1} (V(x_1, x_2) \psi)=V(x_1, x_2) \partial_{x1}\psi + \partial_{x1}V(x_1, x_2) \psi$$
$$\implies V(x_1, x_2) \partial_{x1}\psi-\partial_{x1} (V(x_1, x_2) \psi)=[V,\partial_{x1}]\psi=-\partial_{x1}V(x_1, x_2) \psi$$

The derivative of the potential is

$$\partial_{x1}V(x_1, x_2)=\frac{k(x_2-x_1)}{|x_2-x_1|^3}$$

Therefore $[V(x_1, x_2),\partial_{x1}]=\frac{k(x_2-x_1)}{|x_2-x_1|^3}$. This gives

$$[V(x_1, x_2),p_1]=-i\hbar\frac{k(x_2-x_1)}{|x_2-x_1|^3}$$
$$[V(x_1, x_2),p_2]=+i\hbar\frac{k(x_2-x_1)}{|x_2-x_1|^3}$$

..where the second commutator came from exchanging $x_1 \leftrightarrow x_2$. These commutators are negatives of each other, so adding them gives
$$[V(x_1, x_2),p_1+p_2]=[V(x_1, x_2),p]=0$$
$$\implies [H,p]=0$$

This is a proof in one spacial dimension. The same proof works for the Coulomb potential in three spacial dimensions, where the generalized result is $[H,p_i]=0$ for all three components of the momentum.

Comment: Why is this dead-wrong answer getting upvoted? The claim that "Energy and momentum can commute in a non-constant potential" is patently false, and has nothing to do with the actual answer to the question at hand.

Comment: Added the proof. I believe this answer is actually helpful to OP, or else I would delete it.

Comment: That's a remarkable exercise in semantic gymnastics. Yes, if you go to a two-dimensional configuration space and you use a potential which is constant in one direction but not another, then one component of momentum will be conserved and the other one won't. But no, that has nothing to do with what any reasonable person would interpret your original claim to mean. This answer continues to be wrong, and cures no misconceptions exhibited by OP. (The OP is explicitly in 1D; if you need to invoke more degrees of freedom, then you're way out of scope.)

Comment: I think you misread my answer. All three components of the combined momentum operator for two particles, $\vec{p}=\vec{p}_1+\vec{p}_2$ are conserved. The potential is also not constant in any direction, it is the standard coulomb potential. I wrote the "..." because all 3 directions were implicit. In case that wasn't clear I'll edit away that shorthand in the definition of V. I did it in 3 dimensions but the proof is exactly the same (actually simpler) in 1d.

Comment: No, I didn't misread your answer, but you misread my comment. If you want to insist on proliferating dimensions from 1 to 3 per particle, then you've increased the dimension of the configuration space to *six* instead of two; from those six dimensions, the potential is constant along three orthogonal directions. And again: if your answer does not fit in a *single* dimension, it does not fit in this thread, it does not correct any "misconception" exhibited by OP, and it does not help OP or anyone else, or indeed do anything other than add confusion where none was needed.

Comment: I updated the answer to be in one dimension. I don't see any problems with the proof, if you do I would learn something from it.

Comment: I don't see anything in this post that's in one dimension - all I see is a scale-back from six dimensions to two, and I don't see anything that's relevant to the dimensionality of the problem posed by OP. I've explained the problems here as clearly as I can, but it's ultimately you that needs to get the point if this answer is to be fixed. I stand by my downvote and strong disagreement to the upvotes.

Comment: My answer was only in response to OP's premise that $[H,P]\neq 0$ in general whenever $V$ is not constant. I think we've interpreted that premise different based on the context of the question. I gave a counterexample to that premise, as a hopefully helpful reply but not a complete answer. I changed the answer to one spacial dimension (from 3), but we had a different understanding of the word dimension so I guess that wasn't necessary. If you agree that that premise is false in general, then I think we agree on everything.

Comment: OP's premise is perfectly valid in its context. I don't see how it is helpful to take it out of that context just to try and punch holes in a post by a newcomer that didn't have any.

Comment: To the downvoters: I would be interested to know why you think this answer is not useful to OP. I tried to correct a mistake of OP in good faith, and provided a proof for what I wrote, for which no mistakes have been pointed out. I know that the mistake was not the source of OP's confusion, but as an asker I would always be interested if I have a misconception in my understanding, & would welcome such a reply. If this type of answer is not in line with site policy, I don't know about it, and would be interested to see a reference.